# making correct sense of reconciliation

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've written a small react/redux based app ([github](https://github.com/deostroll/reduxmin3)). Its based on the swagger-ui redux system. So I made up some tree-like data and rendered that out on the UI.

Warning: the redux system might take some time to get used to. Its not traditional. It is a quasi plugin-based architecture.

So my tree-view component acts on the following data -> https://github.com/deostroll/reduxmin3/blob/master/dev-helpers/data/sample.json

The code for the tree-view is as follows:

```
export default class TreeView extends React.Component {

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        if (this.previousState) {
            let {layoutSelectors } = nextProps
            let prevValue = this.previousState.expand
            let currentValue = layoutSelectors.isExpanded(this.previousState.path)
            console.log('Path:', this.previousState.path.join('.'), 'Result:', currentValue !== prevValue)
            return currentValue !== prevValue
        }
        return false
    }

    setVisibility = (flag) => {
        // console.log('foo')
        let { _path, layoutActions } = this.props
        if (flag) {
            layoutActions.show(_path)
        }
        else {
            layoutActions.hide(_path)
        }

    }

    renderChild() {
        // console.log('render child')
        let { _path, _tree, dataSelectors, getComponent, layoutSelectors } = this.props
        console.log('Render:', _path.join('.'))
        let data = _tree.getIn(_path)
        // console.assert(data, path)
        let paras = data && data.get ? (data.get("paras") ? data.get("paras") : undefined) : undefined

        let expand = layoutSelectors.isExpanded(_path)

        let childCount = dataSelectors.childCount(_path)
        // console.log({path: _path, count: childCount, data: data})
        this.previousState = {
            path: _path,
            expand: expand
        }
        let TreeView = getComponent("TreeView")
        // console.log('path:', _path, 'hasChildren:', hasChildren)
        // layoutSelectors.isRoot(_path)
        let hide = () => this.setVisibility(false)
        let show = () => this.setVisibility(true)
        return (
            <div className={ `child ${ _path.length === 1 ? "root" : "" }`}>
                { data && data.get && data.get("title") ? <h3>{data.get("title")}</h3> : null }
                <small>Children Count:  { childCount }</small>
                { 
                    childCount ? <div className="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
                                    <div className="btn-group" role="group">
                                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-default btn-xs" onClick={ show }>
                                                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-default btn-xs" onClick={ hide }>
                                                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close"></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div> 
                                : null
                }


                {
                    (expand && paras) ? paras.map((obj, key) => {
                        let thisPath = _path.concat("paras", key)
                        return <TreeView _path={ thisPath } _tree={ _tree } key={ `-${thisPath.join('.')}` }/>
                    }) : null
                }
            </div>
        )
    }


    renderRoot() {
        // console.log('render root')
        // console.log(this.props)
        let { getState, getComponent } = this.props
        let data = getState().get("data")
        let TV = getComponent("TreeView")
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    data.map( (subtree, key) => {
                        return (
                            <TV _path={ [key] } _tree={ data } key={ `-${key}` } />
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }

    render() {
        let { _path, _tree } = this.props

        let isRoot = () => !_path && !_tree

        if (isRoot()) {
            return this.renderRoot()
        }
        else {
            return this.renderChild()
        }
    }
}
```

The `shouldComponentUpdate` basically logs stuff. So does the `render`. When page is loaded I see something like this:
[image]
The shouldComponentUpdate code didn't execute since its the first render - expected. The logs show something as follows:

```
Render App
Render: 0
Render: 1
Render: 2
Render: 3
```

Now I'll share the output when I want to see all children of the first item, and the first sub item respectively:

```
#First item click
Render App
Path: 0 Result: true
Render: 0
Render: 0.paras.0
Render: 0.paras.1
Render: 0.paras.2
Render: 0.paras.3
Render: 0.paras.4
Path: 1 Result: false
Path: 2 Result: false
Path: 3 Result: false

#first sub item click
Render App
Path: 0 Result: false
Path: 1 Result: false
Path: 2 Result: false
Path: 3 Result: false
Path: 0.paras.0 Result: true
Render: 0.paras.0
Render: 0.paras.0.paras.0
Render: 0.paras.0.paras.1
Render: 0.paras.0.paras.2
Path: 0.paras.1 Result: false
Path: 0.paras.2 Result: false
Path: 0.paras.3 Result: false
Path: 0.paras.4 Result: false
```

Observations:

1. On first item click - The should component update of the tree-view at that level shows true and its children all renders. This is expected.
2. On sub item click - the should component update of the parent returns false, but the children renders - **This is what I don't understand**...!!! (`Path: 0 Result: false`, but `Path: 0.paras.0 Result: true`)

Comment: Curious... In your `renderRoot()` did you mean to apply `data` to the _tree property of `<TV _path={ [key] } _tree={ data } key={ `-${key}` } />` ? I ask this because it's inside `data.map()` and `subtree` is not used. Also, using an index as a key is known to cause problems. I suggest making it something unique. Might not be the problem, but good start.

Comment: Yes I am incidentally passing the whole data down...and the key is simply a `-` with index at the top level. A bad idea. But it kind of serves the purpose for this contrived example